# How do I log into SalesForce using SOAP in JMeter?

Tags: soap, jmeter, salesforce

My app usually ask the user to log into SalesForce using this URL.

https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=ABC&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3001/callback_URL&state=5abe9eb7b39bae29fcc2dcf9

If successful will call the callbackURL and let the application know login was successful.  I would like to mimic this behavior in JMeter.

I tried following the tutorial in this link exactly:

http://blog.deadlypenguin.com/blog/2017/06/29/jmeter-logging-salesforce/

But it's not return a session ID.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is how I set it up as per the tutorial:

This is the SalesForce information in step:  credentials
[image]

Here is the Login Request, as described in step:  logging in
[image]

Here is the Header config for the login request, as described in the step:  loggin in
[image]

Here is how I save the convsation, as described in the step:  storing session id
[image]

Here is what the request sent look like:

```
POST http://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/42.0

POST data:
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
    <soapenv:Header></soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <urn:login>
            <urn:username>USERNAME</urn:username>
            <urn:password>PASSWORDTOKEN</urn:password>
        </urn:login>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

[no cookies]

Request Headers:
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/xml: charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com/Soap/loginRequest"
Content-Length: 390
Host: test.salesforce.com
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/1.8.0_161)
```

And here is the response back:

```
Formatted XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sf="urn:fault.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>INVALID_LOGIN</faultcode>
         <faultstring>INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <sf:LoginFault xsi:type="sf:LoginFault">
               <sf:exceptionCode>INVALID_LOGIN</sf:exceptionCode>
               <sf:exceptionMessage>Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.</sf:exceptionMessage>
            </sf:LoginFault>
         </detail>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am sure the username and password I used is correct, so there must be some other error.  I notice in the tutorial it append the Token after the password.  Where do I get that?  What token is it talking about?

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert in sales force. But from your description it looks like you are not passing the security token along with the password which is shown in the reference. So, authentication required "Password + Security token". From your first snapshot, I am getting both. i.e. ${SF_Password}${SF_Token}.

Try it and let us know if it solves the issue or not.

Regards,

Comment: Which security token is that?  I am not sure where to get the security token.

Comment: Try the steps:-
1. Login sales force account
2. Go to your name or click User icon 
3. Select Settings/My Profile (This may depend on different versions) 
4. Select My Personal Information 5. There you can find "Reset My Security Token" 6. Follow the instructions